# Opencart2 не выводится опция товара в корзину

Tags: php, opencart, интернет-магазин, корзина

Добавила к товару опцию "Цвет",на карточке товара всё выводиться и радиокнопки переключаются. Но в корзину не попадает, соответственно и в админку-заказы тоже.На форумах написано что когда добавляешь опцию, то она автоматически дожна везде появляться.
В коде не срабатывает этот if:

```
<?php if ($product['option']) { ?>
<?php foreach ($product['option'] as $option) { ?>
<br />
<small><?php echo $option['name']; ?>: <?php echo $option['value']; ?></small>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

В файле buy.tpl. Как будто у товара нету опций, но они есть!

В чём может быть проблема? Как это исправить?
Версия опенкарт 2.1.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Такое поведение характерно для кастомных шаблонов, недоработанных. Судя по имени файла buy.tpl это именно так, такого названия в дефолтном шаблоне нет. Самое правильное решение - отдать проект спецу по oc2. Потому, что проблема может быть где угодно, от файлов представления до недописи базы.